# How to address performance issues when using Entity Framework Core and Include() for large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm developing an application using Entity Framework Core (.NET 6) and I'm encountering performance issues when retrieving data using the `GetQuestionByTest()` method. I want to load data from `TblMultipleChoices` related to the `TblQuestionTest` entity, but the data is quite large, and this is slowing down the application's response time.

Here is a portion of the code that is causing the problem:

```
public IEnumerable<TblQuestionTest> GetQuestionByTest(int tesId)
{
    return context.TblQuestionTests
                  .Include(e => e.Test)
                  .Include(e => e.TblMultipleChoices)
                  .Where(e => e.TestId == tesId);
}
```

How can I address this performance issue given the substantial amount of data? Are there any strategies or techniques I can apply to load the data more efficiently or avoid the delay that's occurring?

Thank you

EDIT:
I apologize if my explanation was not clear to you because I'm new to C#. I'm using scaffold, and my multiple-choice model is as follows:

```
public partial class TblMultipleChoice
{
    public int MultipleChoiceId { get; set; }

    public string? MultipleChoiceDesc { get; set; }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string Score { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual TblQuestionTest Question { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing the structure of the data and without knowing if any index is missing. In other words: you must have identified bottle necks first before we can talk about how to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need all of the entities then you can use `AsSplitQuery()` to remove the Cartesian Product. Otherwise consider using Projection /w `Select()` to reduce the amount of data you retrieve to just what your consuming view needs instead of returning Entities. One risk of returning Entities is that if the consumption causes them to be serialized this can trip you up with lazy loading as other non-eagerly loaded properties get "touched" and loaded.

For instance in MVC using the dreaded:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

When working with view models something like that is useful and fine. When passing entities to a view that is a lazy loading landmine.

Edit: The next step would be to hook up a profiler to the database and run through the scenario where this data is loaded. Inspect the SQL that is generated by EF. If this is SQL Server, run those generated SQL statements with an Execution Plan enabled as this may suggest missing indexes in your schema. Looking at what the profiler reports can also give hints into other problems like unexpected lazy loading hits. For instance, without `.AsSplitQuery()` something like that should generate a single SQL statement with JOINs between the three tables. With `.AsSplitQuery()` you would see 3 separate queries. If you are seeing several queries scrolling by after this call as the page loads etc. then your code is tripping lazy load round trips to load relations that aren't eager loaded.  If you are using `Select()` then you should also be sure to include a `.ToList()` to materialize the query results.

Beyond that, what are the typical number of questions, and the # of multiple choices per question? Typically most multiple choice questions have 4 or 5 choices, so even if you have 100 questions, that is only 400-500 "choices" which EF should be able to fetch and materialize in a second or so. However, if MultipleChoices references another table that you "touch" when iterating through the questions and choices, the lazy loads would be kicked off for each individual choice, one by one, which can seriously slow down querying.

If you are still having issues, expand your question with the entity definitions in question, Test, QuestionTest, and MultipleChoice so we can see how these are related, and hints at what might be misconfigured or could be optimized. So far there seems to be a possible missing link as "QuestionTest" implies a joining table between a "Question" and a "Test".

Edit #2: Just looking at the MultipleChoices definition you provided: EF won't automatically wire up the QuestionId as the FK to the Question navigation property as the default convention is based on the type name (TblQuestionTest). So for a navigation property:

```
public virtual TblQuestionTest Question { get; set; } = null!;
```

the FK EF would be looking for would be "TblQuestionTestId" not "QuestionId". To use QuestionId as the FK you would want:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(QuestionId))]
public virtual TblQuestionTest Question { get; set; } = null!;
```

or there will need to be explicit configuration to nominate the FK.

Comment: I have tried using select(), but it still takes a long time

Comment: I have indeed tried using `AsSplitQuery()`, but I'm still facing significant performance issues. I've also made other efforts to optimize the query, but haven't managed to resolve the issue.
btw I used the repository to create an API and consume using ajax

Comment: I have updated my response with some further details to check.

Comment: I also think as you meant about MultipleChoices iterating one by one. but i have no idea how to hanlde that

Comment: Would need to see TblQuestionTest and TblTest as well to see how these are related. also any configuration (I.e. OnModelCreating()/modelBuilder declarations) for these entities.  Already I see potential issues with the mapping, though nothing that points at a performance issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

u can try to improve the performance of loading
Use explicit loading instead of eager loading with `Include()`. Retrieve the `TblQuestionTest` entities first without related data, then use `context.Entry(entity).Collection(x => x.TblMultipleChoices).Load()` to load the TblMultipleChoices only when needed. This avoids loading unnecessary data upfront.

use projection to select only the needed data properties instead of entire entities. For example:

```
var questions = context.TblQuestionTests
                      .Where(e => e.TestId == tesId)
                      .Select(q => new {
                          q.Id,
                          q.Text,
                          Choices = q.TblMultipleChoices
                                      .Select(c => new {c.Id, c.Text}) 
                      });
```

use AsNoTracking() when you don't need to track entity changes. This avoids the overhead of change tracking.

use explicit compilation of queries to cache and reuse query plans.

batch loading of related entities by ID can be more efficient than loading entire collections.

for very large datasets, consider using a stateless, read-optimized model with DTOs instead of EF entity classes.

set maximum depths for recursive relationships to avoid over-fetching data.